# Ich habe nie gesehen, dass ich diesen Weg gegangen bin

Tags: verb, tense

In https://de.quora.com/Warum-sollten-sich-Menschen-nicht-mit-schrecklichen-Berufen-abfinden , I have read the following:

> Ich wurde eher als ein Typ von Make-Love-nicht-Krieg geboren. Ich habe nie gesehen, dass ich diesen Weg gegangen bin.

My first attempt to translate the second sentence was "I have never seen that I took that path". That doesn't made much sense to me and therefore I didn't understand the usage of the past in the second part of that sentence.

I was only able to understand the sentence when I translated the sentence in DeepL translator: "I never saw myself going that way". Why is the past used instead of the conditional (gehen würde), if the action of "going that way" is imaginary ?

Comment: Not your question, but splitting "Make love, not war" in the middle and only translating half seems very suspect. Either leave as is or *Mach Liebe, nicht Krieg*. I don't know if the phrase is really translatable though. To me it's strongly associated with Vietnam War era protests and I don't know if people living outside the US would have had the same experience. Then there's the fact that the "boomers" of today were called "the younger generation" at the time.

Comment: It's a machine translation. The link to the original English question is just above it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just bad German, and even I as a native speaker have to look twice to understand it, it looks like a Google translate of some English piece or a bot.

Correct, this the text would be
"Ich wurde eher als ein 'Make-Love-Not-War'-Typ geboren. Ich hätte nie gedacht, dass ich diesen Weg gehen würde."

or

"Ich wurde eher als ein 'Make-Love-Not-War'-Typ geboren. Ich hätte mich nie diesen Weg gehen gesehen"

Comment: Indeed the source says just in front of the Text: "Diese Antwort ist möglicherweise keine exakte Übersetzung der Antwort von Sean Kernan auf Quora auf Englisch." So it is a machine translation.